# Quarto listing search only one directory deep

Tags: r, quarto

I am making a quarto blog with "series" that I am structuring as subdirectories. To keep top-level directories cleaner, I want a structure as shown below.

My nav item "Series" loads the page `/series/series.qmd`. Right now, it dives down into all of the series sub-directories and lists ALL articles. I would like it to only display the `qmd` file at the top level of each series. E.g. `/series/linux_series/linux_series.qmd`, `/series/ssh_series/ssh_series.qmd`.

This is what the file `/series/series.qmd` looks like:

```
---
title: "Series"
listing:
  contents: "*/*.qmd"
  sort: "title asc"
  type: default
  categories: true
  sort-ui: true
  filter-ui: true
  fields: [image, date, title, author, reading-time]
  image-height: 240px
  image-align: left
page-layout: full
title-block-banner: false
knitr:
  opts_chunk: 
    collapse: true
execute: 
  echo: false
---
```

I've tried some other ideas for `contents` such as `./*/*.qmd`, `/series/*/*.qmd`, `../series/*/*.qmd`.

```
(base) balter@expiyes:~/quarto-blog-1$ tree -F --filesfirst
./
├── _quarto.yml
├── index.qmd
├── profile.jpg
├── series/
│   ├── series.qmd
│   ├── linux_series/
│   │   ├── linux_series.qmd
│   │   ├── about_linux/
│   │   │   └── about_linux.qmd
...
...
│   │   └── why_use_linux/
│   │       └── why_use_linux.qmd
│   ├── software_packages_and_libraries.qmd/
│   │   ├── software_packages_and_libraries.qmd
│   │   ├── conda/
│   │   │   └── conda.qmd
...
...
│   │   └── r_libraries/
│   │       └── r_libraries.qmd
│   └── ssh_series/
│       ├── ssh_series.qmd
│       ├── about_ssh/
│       │   └── what_is_ssh.qmd
...
...
│       └── ssh_keys/
│           └── ssh_keys.qmd
```

Comment: I get it's hard to make a reprex in your post for this kind of problem, but maybe you could make an example github repo with a minimal structure?